# Is it ever possible to design an Oracle trigger that modifies same table (guaranteed not same row)?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I need to write a TRIGGER that preserves the old value of a column *before* it is updated, by inserting or updating the old value *into another row in the same table.* (yes, I know).
The following MERGE/DUAL trickery has served me well,
but because in this case, I'm inserting into or updating the same table,
Oracle complains at runtime.  Also, for some reason, I found it unusually difficult to write code that compiles without errors.

**Two questions:**

1. Is it *ever* possible to modify the same table that the trigger is on, even when I can *guarantee* that the trigger will never update the row that triggered the trigger?  Or do I have to do something like (e.g.): insert pending changes into *another* table, so that a 2nd trigger can merge them back into the *original* table? (This table is a customer interface, so I can't re-architect this to use a second table for permanently storing old values.)
2. What's with the compiler errors that *don't* let me use **:old.event_key,** but *do* let me use **:old.property_val** in the MERGE statement?  (declaring a variable **old_event_key** and assigning it to the value of **:old.event_key** *seems* to work) Is there some sort of *hidden intermediate language* that knows when a column is (part of) the primary key, and prevents you from referencing it via **:old.**?

Here is the offending code:

```
create or replace trigger remember_old_status
  before update on event_properties
  for each row
    when (old.property_name = 'CURRENT-STATUS')
    declare
      old_event_key varchar2(20);
    begin
      old_event_key := :old.event_key;
      merge into event_properties eprop
        using (select 1 from dual) dummy
        on (    eprop.event_key = old_event_key
            AND eprop.property_name = 'PREVIOUS-STATUS')
        when matched then
          update set property_val = :old.property_val
        when not matched then
          insert (event_key, property_name, property_val)
          values (old_event_key, 'PREVIOUS-STATUS', :old.property_val);
    end;
```

And here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "CUST"."EVENT_PROPERTIES" 
 (  "EVENT_KEY" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) CONSTRAINT "NN_FLE_FLK" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "PROPERTY_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) CONSTRAINT "NN_FLE_PN" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "PROPERTY_VAL" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
   CONSTRAINT "PX_EVENT_PROPERTIES" PRIMARY KEY ("EVENT_KEY", "PROPERTY_NAME") DEFERRABLE
USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "CUST_TS"  ENABLE
 ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "CUST_TS" ;
```

And here are the error messages:

> ORA-04091: table CUST.EVENT_PROPERTIES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
>   ORA-06512: at "CUST.REMEMBER_OLD_STATUS", line 5

Comment: Have a look at these examples: https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions . One of them shows how to use "another table" (you mentioned) - which is a **global temporary table**, while the second option demonstrates usage of a **collection in package variable**.

Comment: Any examination of Oracle documentation or searching this site on `ORA-04091` will clearly give you the answer "No". You cannot perform DML on the table triggered `for each row`. The pattern to solve this is to use the `for each row` to update another table. Then have an `after` statement level trigger consume the information from that other table to update the triggered table.

Comment: What compiler errors are you referring to in the second part of the question? Using `old.event_key` directly in your code compiles OK. Well, it isn't helpful to ask two questions in one anyway; you should ask a separate question about that showing the actual code and error, if you can still reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [a compound trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-8A0DA171-BE6A-4798-A1A4-677B88EA16A0) to do this, storing the old values in variables in a `before each row` section, and then merging in an `after statement`.

This assumes you'll only ever update one row at a time:

```
create or replace trigger remember_old_status
for update on event_properties
compound trigger

  old_rec event_properties%rowtype;

  before each row is
  begin
    if (:old.property_name = 'CURRENT-STATUS') then
      old_rec.event_key := :old.event_key;
      old_rec.property_name := :old.property_name;
      old_rec.property_val := :old.property_val;
    end if;
  end before each row;

  after statement is
  begin
    if (old_rec.property_name = 'CURRENT-STATUS') then
      merge into event_properties eprop
        using (
          select old_rec.event_key as event_key, 
            'PREVIOUS-STATUS' as property_name,
            old_rec.property_val as property_val
            from dual
        ) dummy
        on (eprop.event_key = dummy.event_key
            and eprop.property_name = dummy.property_name)
        when matched then
          update set property_val = old_rec.property_val
        when not matched then
          insert (event_key, property_name, property_val)
          values (dummy.event_key, dummy.property_name, dummy.property_val);
    end if;
  end after statement;
end remember_old_status;
/
```

Quick test:

```
insert into event_properties values('SOME_EVENT', 'CURRENT-STATUS', 'A');

1 row inserted.

update event_properties set property_val = 'B' where event_key = 'SOME_EVENT' and property_name = 'CURRENT-STATUS';

1 row updated.

select * from event_properties;

EVENT_KEY            PROPERTY_NAME        PROPERTY_VAL                                                                    
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOME_EVENT           CURRENT-STATUS       B                                                                               
SOME_EVENT           PREVIOUS-STATUS      A                                                                               

update event_properties set property_val = 'C' where event_key = 'SOME_EVENT' and property_name = 'CURRENT-STATUS';

1 row updated.

select * from event_properties;

EVENT_KEY            PROPERTY_NAME        PROPERTY_VAL                                                                    
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOME_EVENT           CURRENT-STATUS       C                                                                               
SOME_EVENT           PREVIOUS-STATUS      B
```

If you want to deal with multiple updates on one statement then the `before each row` can populate a collection instead, and you can then use that in the `after statement`.

```
create or replace trigger remember_old_status
for update on event_properties
compound trigger

  type t_type is table of event_properties%rowtype;
  old_recs t_type := t_type();

  before each row is
  begin
    if (:old.property_name = 'CURRENT-STATUS') then
      old_recs.extend();
      old_recs(old_recs.count).event_key := :old.event_key;
      old_recs(old_recs.count).property_name := :old.property_name;
      old_recs(old_recs.count).property_val := :old.property_val;
    end if;
  end before each row;

  after statement is
  begin
    forall i in old_recs.first..old_recs.last
      merge into event_properties eprop
        using (
          select old_recs(i).event_key as event_key, 
            'PREVIOUS-STATUS' as property_name,
            old_recs(i).property_val as property_val
            from dual
        ) dummy
        on (eprop.event_key = dummy.event_key
            and eprop.property_name = dummy.property_name)
        when matched then
          update set property_val = old_recs(i).property_val
        when not matched then
          insert (event_key, property_name, property_val)
          values (dummy.event_key, dummy.property_name, dummy.property_val);
  end after statement;
end remember_old_status;
/
```